# Apache web server not working on https port work on http

Tags: apache, https, webserver, httpd.conf, proxypass

Good day,

I have a apache web server (10.8.112.65), I configure ProxyPass to direct it to my app server, the ProxyPass code is as follow in the httpd.conf:

```
ProxyPass "/mfp" "http://101.7.2.63:9080/mfp"
ProxyPassReverse "/mfp" "http://101.7.2.63:9080/mfp"
```

And its listen to port 80

```
Listen 80
```

This is working fine, From my device, I fire a `http url` request to 10.8.112.65, it will direct to `http://101.7.2.63:9080/mfp` to process. For example:

Fire `http://10.8.112.65/mfp/api/adapters/MyAdapter/public/init/`
It will direct to `http://101.7.2.63:9080/mfp/api/adapters/MyAdapter/public/init/` , this is good.

However, From my device, I need to fire a `https url` request instead of `http`. Thus, I change the Listen port to 443, and I try to fire https request as follow:

Fire `https://10.8.112.65:443/mfp/api/adapters/MyAdapter/public/init/`

This one could not reach to my app server, and from the web server access log, I saw it print out

```
10.3.131.36 - - [13/Feb/2020:18:58:01 +0800] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 226 "-" "-"
10.3.131.36 - - [13/Feb/2020:18:58:01 +0800] "\x16\x03\x01\x02" 400 226 "-" "-"
```

Where 10.3.131.36 is my device ip address.

I try to search google for this, but didnt get any result that I understand.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Is there anything in error log?

Comment: @DusanBajic, nothing show in error log.